# Calculate distance between LineString and Point in meters

Tags: python, python-3.x, geopandas

I have LineString and Point, and I want to calculate distance between them in meters:

- line = LINESTRING (7.301606 52.5602366, 7.300065099999999 52.5587741)
- point = POINT (8.02 52.303333)

I use: line.distance(point). I got a distance, but I don't know how to convert to meters or km. I am using geopandas, and I read that unit is CRS. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What units is it in now?

Comment: And how are we supposed to guess the original units? Remember the only information others have is the content of your question...

Comment: I updated the question. It is geopandas unit CRS

Answer (score 0):

- as per comments you need to specify the CRS *I am using geopandas, and I read that unit is CRS.* I assume by this statement you mean WSG84 CRS, which is **EPSG:4326**
- given limitation of **geopandas** to have only one geometry column per *GeoDataFrame* have put *LINESTRING* and *POINT* into separate data frames
- project from WSG84 onto UTM CRS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system.   This then means co-ordinates are expressed in meters.  This will not work if *LINESTRING* and *POINT* are in different UTM zones
- then it's exceptionally simple to use https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.distance.html

```
import shapely.wkt
import geopandas as gpd

gdfl = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[shapely.wkt.loads("LINESTRING (7.301606 52.5602366, 7.300065099999999 52.5587741)")], crs="EPSG:4326")
gdfp = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[shapely.wkt.loads("POINT (8.02 52.303333)")], crs="EPSG:4326")
utm = gdfl.estimate_utm_crs()
gdfl.to_crs(utm).distance(gdfp.to_crs(utm))
```

#### output

```
56592.878178
```

Comment: thank you a lot. One question: is it in meters or km?

Comment: meters - it's fully covered in the wikipedia link in the answer.  It's worth understanding UTM CRS if you are doing anything with mapping. CRS == Co-ordinate reference system,  without defining which one it's meaningless.  Hence reason for comments on your question and why I stated I have assumed WSG:4326